# How to constrain a parameter type to allow only std::initializer_list<size_t> or std::array<size_t, N>?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I would like to have only one template function. So I came up with like...

```
template<typename Iteratable, size_t N,
         typename = 
            std::enable_if_t<
                std::is_same_v<Iteratable, const std::initializer_list<size_t> > ||
                std::is_same_v<Iteratable, const std::array<size_t, N > >
            > 
>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, Iteratable& in) {
    std::copy(std::begin(in), std::end(in), std::ostream_iterator<size_t>(os, " ") ); 
    return os;
}
```

It seems because of `N` in `std::array<size_t, N>`, the specialization fails.

Is there any how not to write 2 function for this use case?

Comment: Two functions would be 9 lines of code, and now you spend 11 lines trying to avoid code duplication?  :-) But you are right about the `N` not being deducible from the initializer_list.

Answer (score 8):

If the sole reason you don't want to overload is to avoid duplicating the function body, you can instead go for writing your own trait. One such way:

```
namespace details {
  template<class Iterable>
  struct writable : std::false_type {};

  template<size_t N>
  struct writable<std::array<std::size_t, N>> : std::true_type {};

  template<>
  struct writable<std::initializer_list<size_t>> : std::true_type {};

  template<class Iterable>
  constexpr bool writable_v = writable<Iterable>::value;
}

template<typename Iteratable,
         std::enable_if_t<details::writable_v<std::decay_t<Iteratable>>,
         int> = 0 
>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, Iteratable& in) {
    std::copy(std::begin(in), std::end(in), std::ostream_iterator<size_t>(os, " ") ); 
    return os;
}
```

I also took the liberty of moving the `enable_if` to the template argument. That way SFINAE cannot be circumvented by specifying a type name for both arguments (though admittedly, it's unlikely to happen for an overloaded operator).

Another nice fact about it is that the customization point is now decoupled from the function definition itself. Adding new iterables is just a matter of adding another specialization for `details::writable`.

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9744fc2606cbd859)

Comment: That expresses my intension on point. By the way, I'm a new for sfinae, would you please explain more about the enable_if idioms `typename = enable_if` and `enable_if = 0`.

Comment: @sandthorn - 9 out of 10 times they serve the same purpose. There are a few caveats however. (1) Default arguments don't differentiate two otherwise identical overloads. You'll come upon it if you happen to try and SFINAE a collection of mutually exclusive c'tors. (2) For cases where the arguments may be specified explicitly, something like `my_func<std::vector<std::size_t>, bool>` could entirely bypass the SFINAE check.

Comment: How about this: `enable_if_t<  ,std::errc> = std::errc::operation_not_supported` : would the strong-ly-typed-ness of `enum class` help improve SFINAE-ity and express intend at the same time?

Comment: @sandthorn - Yeah, an enumeration is a valid non-type template parameter, so that will work. Don't know how often it's done in practice however. You must remember that SFINAE is usually for disqualifying an overloaded function from a set of overloads. Meaning there will be no error to look at, but another overload will be chosen.